# Backreference search replace with trailing numeral

Tags: search, vim, replace, backreference

I'm using vim to find a four digit number and replace the last digit, but unlike new school sed which uses the `${1}` value for a back reference, it uses `\1` and I'm struggling to append the following number. I need to do:

- a=1234 => a=1235
- b=1374 => b=1375

I think I need `s/\(=[0-9]\{3\}\)4/=\1<xxx>5/g`
where  is a zero length char.
I tried `s/\(=[0-9]\{3\}\)4/=${1}5/g` but it didn't use the backreference. 
Interestingly`s/\(=[0-9]\{3\}\)4/=\15/g` does it correctly, but there's a corner case when there is actually 15 back reference groups...

Comment: Personally, I'd just use a search pattern to find four digit numbers and `<C-a>` each one as I found them...

Comment: There are no 15 backreference groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can only be 9 submatches. `\1` to `\9` and `\0` which is the whole match. You can see this in the help in `:help s/\1` or `:help /\1` where it only list 1 through 9. So there is no ambiguity for a trailing number. `\15` is always the first submatch followed by a 5. You also get an error if you have more then 9.

If you use all of them your regex is probably too complex.

---

If you wanted to do the addition in a substitute command, I would use substitute with an expression. This is done by placing `\=` as the start of the replacement and the thing that follows it is treated as a vim expression.

```
:s/=\zs\d\+/\=submatch(0) + 1/g
```

The help page for this feature is `:help sub-replace-expression`

Comment: Wonderful: I didn't realise Posix regex/GNU-ERE were limited to 0-9; I discovered this which compares regex backreference limits: http://www.dziury.eu/sennik/index.php?artikle=1296

Comment: @rupert160 vim regex is not Posix or GNU-ERE.